# Is there any way to automate the publication of application to Android Market?

Tags: android, deployment, automation

Is there an official API, library, tool which could allow me to automate the process of uploading a new Android application version to Android Market?

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, there is nothing officially available for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now there is one way to do that!

Just use the [Google's Publishing API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing):

> The Google Play Developer Publishing API allows you to automate
>   frequent tasks having to do with app production and distribution. This
>   provides functions similar to those available to a developer through
>   the Developer Console, such as:
>
> - Uploading new versions of an app
> - Releasing apps, by assigning APKs to various Tracks (alpha, beta, staged rollout, or production)
> - Creating and modifying Google Play Store listings, including localized text and graphics and multi-device screenshots
>
> Those tasks are performed using the new edits functionality, which
>   take a transactional approach to making changes; you bundle several
>   changes into a single draft edit, then commit the changes all at once.
>   (None of the changes take effect until the edit is committed.)

To ease your pain, [Google provides Client Libraries and Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/libraries) ;-)